# Friction and Electric Forces

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, friction

As I understand, friction arises from electromagnetic forces. Electric fields, at least static ones, exert conservative forces. So how is it that friction is non-conservative?

Comment: Ah, darn I thought I was the first to ask. But this is exactly what I am looking for thanks!